# Dash dropdown wont reset values once x clicked

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I created 2 Dash dropdowns where one dropdown (the lower) is based on the selection in the first dropdown (the upper)

[image]

The selection and everything work fine.

However, when I click the X button to remove all the options from the area-dropdown, it does remove all the options but still, city-dropdown values are the same as when I clicked the X button.

why won't it reset?

This is the code I'm using:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("city-dropdown", "options"),
    Input("area-dropdown", "value"),
)
def update_city_dropdown(areas):
    if areas is None or None in areas or areas == []:
        return []

    _area_codes = area_codes['area'][area_codes['name'].isin(areas)]
    cities = city_codes['name'][city_codes['area'].isin(_area_codes)]
    return [{'label': city, 'value': city} for city in cities]
```

where:

```
area_dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(
    options=area_codes['name'],
    placeholder="Select an area",
    multi=True,
    style=DROPDOWN_STYLE,
    id='area-dropdown'
)

city_dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(
    placeholder="Select a city",
    options=[],
    multi=True,
    style=DROPDOWN_STYLE,
    id='city-dropdown'
)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `city_dropdown.value` isn't updated, so upon re-selection of an area, the cities show-up again (since those values are now again in the refreshed `options`).

You can add the following callback:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("city-dropdown", "value"), 
    Input("area-dropdown", "value")
)
def clear_city_dropdown(value):
    return []
```

Note that the above will reset your cities when switching areas.